# Mock current time or freeze date/time in WDIO

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webdriver-io

I am writing a test in WebDriverIO, where age is calculated dynamically. This creates issue as snapshot updates every month with new age value and build fails. Is there any way to mock or freeze current date/time, which will not update the age?

I tried updating DOM elements which did not work, as they are not user editable.